# Switching to Terminal-only fails

Tags: command-line

I attempt to switch to terminal-only using

```
sudo service stop lightdm
```

and this turns off the GUI, but I can't type in any commands, although there is a cursor that shows up. I'm not sure what's happening, so any guidance on terminal mode would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `tty1` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

You can switch back usually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>